# R: mean pairwise differences in string vectors

Tags: r, string

I have a big list (10,000 items) of string vectors (50 elements each).
Here is a small sample from a vector:

```
c("0101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000100000000000000100000000000000000110000000000000000000000", 
"0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000001000000000000001000000010000000000000000000000000000000000001", 
"0000000000000000000100010000000010000000000000010000000000100000000000000100000001000001100000000000001000001000000100000000000000000000000000000100")
```

In every vector, I would like to estimate all pairwise differences (ie number of different characters in each pair) and then estimate the mean.
Given the big size of the list, what would be a cost effective way to do so?
thank you!!

**EDIT- UPDATE**

I am adding an example with shorter vectors and expected output (same as my comment below):

```
a=c("0010100101",
    "1001011101",
    "1111111010")
```

expected result (mean of pairwise differences):
6.666667

Many thanks to @Roland for providing the solution, based on Levenshtein distance!

Comment: Can you show your expected output for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not terribly clear but you appear to want a Levenshtein distance:

```
x = c("0010100101",
    "1001011101",
    "1111111010")

#switch off deletions and insertions:
d <- adist(x, costs = list(ins=Inf, del=Inf, sub=1)) 
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    6    8
#[2,]    6    0    6
#[3,]    8    6    0

mean(d[upper.tri(d)])
#[1] 6.666667
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am not sure I understand "adist". In my example,  for a=c("0010100101",
    "1001011101",
    "1111111010") , it does not give the expected results, I think (ie as in my solution)

Comment: @tzema Fixed it. Please add the expected result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realised the small data sample was not that short, so I repeat the example with shorter strings:

```
a=c("0010100101",
    "1001011101",
    "1111111010")
```

I came up with this solution:

```
library(stringdist)

# matrix with no. of pairwise different characters
xx=(1-outer(a,a,"stringsim",method="hamming"))*nchar(a[1])

> xx
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    6    8
[2,]    6    0    6
[3,]    8    6    0


# mean no. of pairwise differences
xx1=mean(xx[lower.tri(xx,diag = FALSE)])

> xx1
[1] 6.666667
```

The result is fine, but I am not sure if this is an ideal solution, though..
(and if the "hamming" method is the correct one for any case).